# Average votes aggregation in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID   vote1   vote2   vote3    agg_vote
1     -1      -1       1        -1
2      0       0      -1        -1
3      1       1      -1         1
4      0       1       0         1
...
```

I tried to aggregate the result from each voter. But if I simply added them together it will give a misleading result which most voted results masked by multiple `0`s. For example, in `ID = 2`, most voters picked 0 but aggregated results give you -1. The same happened in `ID = 4`.How can I correct my calculation here?

Final output will be like,

```
ID   vote1   vote2   vote3    agg_vote
1     -1      -1       1        -1
2      0       0      -1         0
3      1       1      -1         1
4      0       1       0         0
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like `mode`

```
df['new']=df.filter(regex='^vote').mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
df
Out[134]: 
   ID  vote1  vote2  vote3  agg_vote  new
0   1     -1     -1      1        -1   -1
1   2      0      0     -1        -1    0
2   3      1      1     -1         1    1
3   4      0      1      0         1    0
```

Update question check row 4 it return -1

```
   ID  vote1  vote2  vote3  agg_vote
0   1     -1     -1      1        -1
1   2      0      0     -1        -1
2   3      1      1     -1         1
3   4      0      1     -1         1
df.filter(regex='^vote').mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
Out[161]: 
0   -1.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3   -1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi YOBEN, thanks for the answer. I have one more condition that when three voters give you -1, 0, and 1 that by using mode will only return -1. How do I avoid this and return it as 0?

Comment: @JiayuZhang it will return -1 :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just fixed it using `sum_vote` column :) `df['agg_vote'] = np.where(df['sum_vote']==0,0,df['agg_vote'])`